# GreenDroid and MapActivity

Tags: android, mapactivity, greendroid

plz how i can use greendroid library with MapActivity

```
  public class GreendroidTestActivity extends GDActivity   MapActivity
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GDMapActivity`

Example:

https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid/blob/master/GDCatalog/src/com/cyrilmottier/android/gdcatalog/MapPinMapActivity.java